# How to prevent negative count?

Tags: android

I am trying to create a simple mathematical quiz that can not create negative numbers in questions or count them, but I am not sure how I need to approach this. I don't want to make a big list of questions that includes every number from 0 to 15 for each division etc., as it's pointless.

**My actual code**

```
public void setQuestion() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int lhs = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0,15);
    int rhs = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0,15);

    int randomquestion = rand.nextInt(2);
    if (randomquestion == 1) {
        question.setText("What is  " + lhs + " + " + rhs + "?");
        expected = "" + (lhs + rhs);
    } else if (randomquestion == 2 ) {
        question.setText("What is  " + lhs + " - " + rhs + "?");
        expected = "" + (lhs - rhs);
    } else {
        question.setText("What is " + lhs +  " * " + rhs + "?");
        expected = "" + (lhs * rhs);
    }
    sumanswer.setText("You have got " + correctanswer +" CORRECT and " + wronganswer + " WRONG");
```

Comment: rand.nextInt(2) returns 0 or 1, never 2, so your logic is flawed, you should call rand.nextInt(3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you don't want a negative number result in the subtraction section? You can do some simple math to ensure that the smaller of the two numbers is subtracted from the larger number. Try this:

```
question.setText("What is " + Math.Max(lhs, rhs) + " - " + Math.Min(lhs, rhs) + "?");
expected = "" + (Math.Max(lhs, rhs) - Math.Min(lhs, rhs));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, in the else if of the "-", you put a condition that the lhs has to be bigger than the rhs.
Something along the lines of this:

```
} else if (randomquestion == 2 ) {
    if(lhs>rhs){
        question.setText("What is  " + lhs + " - " + rhs + "?");
        expected = "" + (lhs - rhs);
    }else{
        question.setText("What is  " + rhs + " - " + lhs + "?");
        expected = "" + (rhs - lhs);
    }
}
```